# Recovering pmf from characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I'm having some trouble trying to recover the probability mass function of a discrete random variable from its characteristic function.

I have seen that some continuous cases, you can recognize that the characteristic function is the inverse Fourier transform of the density function, so you can apply the Fourier transform again. The formula in that case is
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-itx} \phi(t) \mathop{dt}.$$

However, in the discrete case, this integral does not make sense, as it is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-itx} \sum_{n=1}^N P(X=x_n) e^{itx_n} \mathop{dt}
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n=1}^N P(X=x_n)\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{it(x_n-x)} \mathop{dt},$$
which is not integrable. I thought about using an integral over an interval instead, but it is not possible to get the right period since the $x_n$ are arbitrary real numbers.

How do you recover the pmf from the characteristic function?

Comment: The "density" of a discrete random variable is a sum of Dirac delta functions. We have formally that the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta is just the constant function 1. With this you can derive the Fourier transform of a Dirac delta which is not centered at 0, by changing variables and factoring out a constant.

Comment: Another way to say this is to just try to write the characteristic function in terms of the PMF. If $X$ takes on the values $\{ x_k \}_{k=1}^n$ with probabilities $\{ p_k \}_{k=1}^n$ then you get $E(e^{itX})=\sum_{k=1}^n p_k e^{i t x_k}$. So if the characteristic function is given in this form you can read off the pmf.

Comment: @Ian Sorry for being misleading. I don't actually have an explicit characteristic function so I can't read off the $p_k$; I am looking for an inversion formula. I think I understand the Dirac delta argument, but it seems incredibly powerful/formal for an innocent-looking question.

Comment: You've actually written the inversion formula already, it just comes down to making the definition that the inverse Fourier transform of $t \mapsto e^{i t x}$ is $t \mapsto \delta(t-x)$. In particular the inverse Fourier transform of $t \mapsto 1$ is $\delta(t)$.